# Is it possible to include an interaction term in logistic model if the interaction term had no observation in some category?

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction

I tried to do a binary logistic regression.

- y was a binary outcome
- x1 was an independent variable by 5 categories
- x2 was an independent variable by 2 categories

I found that x1 and x2 had the interaction with each other.
Some category in the interaction term 5x2 that had no observation.

For example,
I have total 1,767 observation.

- if x1=0, x2=0 ==> n=1,365
- if x1=0, x2=1 ==> n=63
- if x1=1, x2=0 ==> n=215
- if x1=1, x2=1 ==> n=12
- if x1=2, x2=0 ==> n=43
- **if x1=2, x2=1 ==> n=0**
- if x1=3, x2=0 ==> n=42
- if x1=3, x2=1 ==> n=3
- if x1=4, x2=0 ==> n=24
- **if x1=4, x2=1 ==> n=0**

[image]

If this interaction term was significant in the model, Should I include this term in the model? 
I might have a problem to interpret the results if some category in the interaction term did not have odds ratio.
Or I could interpret only remaining category and discuss about no observation in some crossover category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what will the estimated model be used? If it will be used for predictions with future data, then you will have to decide what to do with future data where this combinations not occurring in your sample do occur.  One simple solution would be to replace those with zero ... except that idea is badly defined, its effect depend on which factor coding you did use.

Otherwise, if your use is mainly for hypothesis testing (or description) there should be no problems, except that you cannot of course say anything about those combinations not occurring in the data. You should ask yourself if they do not occur just by chance, or for some other reason.

Comment: I see clearly with your explanation and I use for hypothesis testing. 
Thank you for your suggestion.